# I.m getting error "Class<Cucumber> cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, automation, cucumber

I'm trying to make a test runner class but I'm getting error 'Class cannot be resolved to a type'

Earlier JRE was set to 1.5 by default but then I changed it to 12 because in some answer's it is written that it is due to JRE.

Here is my code:

```
package LoginRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "C:\\Users\\abhin\\eclipse-workspace\\FreeCRMBDDFramework\\src\\main\\java\\Features",
        glue = "C:\\Users\\abhin\\eclipse-workspace\\FreeCRMBDDFramework\\src\\main\\java\\LoginStepDef"

        )
public class loginRunner {

}
```

Below are the dependencies I have added:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>FreeCRMBDDFramework</groupId>
  <artifactId>FreeCRMBDDFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FreeCRMBDDFramework</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the screenshot of my project build path [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M76XX.png)
Here is the screenshot of JAVA compiler setting 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaJLB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber does not yet support Java 12. Try Java 8.

Comment: I was getting same error with Java 8. But then I removed scope from cucumber- jvm dependency and it worked. Anyway thanks man.